# Mongo $lookup which worked on localhost stopped working in heroku deployment

Tags: express, heroku, mongoose, aggregate, mlab

I used heroku to deploy my mongoose app, while the following aggregate returns proper data on localhost with local mongo server running, it returns empty result on heroku server with mongolab used to handle database there.

Here is query itself:

```
let projects = this.models.Project.aggregate(
[
    {
        $lookup: {from: 'users', localField: 'creator', foreignField: '_id', as: 'creator'}
    },

    { $unwind : "$creator" },

    {
        $project: {
            name: 1,
            updated: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$updated" } },
            creator: 1,
            description: 1
        }
    }
]
)
.exec((err, projects) => {
console.log("fetched projects is this:", projects)
res.send(projects);
});
```

Here is users and projects Schema:

```
    let userSchema = new Schema({
        _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        username: String,
        password: String,
        email: String,
        gender: String,
        address: String
    });

    let projectSchema = new Schema({
        name: String,
        updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        creator: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
        description: String,
        issues: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Issue'}]
    });
```

Connection to mongolab server is properly configured and working, I was able to create user and project instance there.

I think that the core of a problem is that document id looks like this in my localhost :

```
"_id" : ObjectId("56f1ace9e72b71643070e9a0")
```

And like this in mongolab:

```
"_id": {
    "$oid": "57030f0972365f0300c56c88"
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mLab (formerly MongoLab) does not yet support 3.2 - `$lookup` is new in this release.

http://docs.mlab.com/ops/#version-mgmt

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was suspecting something like that

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I came up with this alternative which works with current MongoLab:

```
resources.app.get('/projectsItems', (req, res) => {
    let projects = this.models.Project.aggregate(
        [
            {
                $project: {
                    name: 1,
                    updated: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$updated" } },
                    creator: 1,
                    description: 1
                }
            }
        ]
    )
    .exec((err, projects) => {
        this.models.Project.populate(projects, {path: "creator"}, (err, projects) => {
            console.log("fetched projects is this:", projects)
            res.send(projects);
        });
    });
});
```

For more info on how it worked look [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate).